# Codeigniter 4: How can I access controller methods from a Controllers/api subfolder?

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, codeigniter-4

I'm creating a project with Codeigniter 4. Everything works fine, except for calls to controllers in an "Controllers/api" subfolder.

Server with Rocky Linux release 8.7 (Green Obsidian) ID_LIKE="rhel centos fedora".
Apache Php 8.1

The url of the Usr.php controller is https://test.myweb.com/api/usr , that is, /home/test/public_html/app/Controllers/api/Usr.php

I try to see the content of any of the methods of Usr.php but it doesn't works. The answer is "404 - File Not Found.
HTTP.controllerNotFound"

I have tried to put in app/Config/Routes.php:

```
$route['api/(:any)'] = 'api\$1';
$routes->resource('App\Controllers\api');
$route['api/usr'] = 'https://test.myweb.com/api/Usr';
$route['api/([^/]+)'] = 'api/usr/$1';

$routes->get('api/usr', '\App\Controllers\api\Usr');
```

Without results.
This is Usr.php:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controllers\Api;
use CodeIgniter\Controller;

class Usr extends Controller {

    public function index(){
        echo "OK INDEX";die;
    }
}
```

This is the .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
#Deny Access
RewriteRule "^(.*/)?\.gitignore" - [F,L]
RewriteRule "^(.*/)?\_sql/" - [F,L]
RewriteRule "^(.*/)?doc-project/" - [F,L]
RewriteRule "^(.*/)?\.git/" - [F,L]
RewriteRule "^(.*/)?README.md" - [F,L]

#Force HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{SERVER_ADDR} !=127.0.0.1
RewriteCond %{SERVER_ADDR} !=::1
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/ [L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|php|script|styles|js|css)

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteBase /        
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Try and get it to work in the browser first - that will then rule out Curl/other issues. Check also that the Usr bit in the url is not case sensitive as sometimes that can be a problem.

Comment: Thanks. I have reduced the test to the maximum, I have edited the question. I followed your advice but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Telerín Please, avoid mutating the question in a way that **invalidates** already existing answers. *Questions are not meant to be moving targets.* If you happen to face an entirely different issue, research it, request clarification using comments, or post a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CodeIgniter 4, we **don't** modify the file `system/Config/Routes.php` since it's part of the core CodeIgniter 4 framework. Any changes made there would likely be overridden after a framework upgrade. You should instead add your custom routes definitions in the file: `app/Config/Routes.php`.

[CodeIgniter 4: Setting Routing Rules](https://codeigniter4.github.io/CodeIgniter4/incoming/routing.html#setting-routing-rules)

Secondly, you seem to be mixing the CodeIgniter v3 with the CodeIgniter v4 route definition/rule syntax. I.e:

[Upgrading from 3.x to 4.x / Upgrade Routing](https://codeigniter4.github.io/CodeIgniter4/installation/upgrade_routing.html#upgrade-routing)

*test.myweb.com/api/usr/login*

| # | CI v3 | CI v4 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| route file path | [*application/config/routes.php*](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html#setting-your-own-routing-rules) | [*app/Config/Routes.php*](https://codeigniter4.github.io/CodeIgniter4/incoming/routing.html#setting-routing-rules) |
| route rule | `$route['api/usr/login']['GET'] = 'api/usr/login';` | `$routes->get('api/usr/login', '\App\Controllers\api\Usr::login');` |
| controller path | *application/controllers/api/Usr.php* | *app/Controllers/api/Usr.php* |

##### Addendum

In CodeIgniter 4, don't forget to disable auto-routing. I.e:

*app/Config/Routes.php*

```php
// ...
$routes->setAutoRoute(false);
// ...
```

Comment: Ok, in the routes I was using C3. I will try and comment.

Comment: I have set $routes->setAutoRoute(true). If I set it to false, should I also put all paths for all controllers, system, views, models, etc? Thank you

Comment: Important: I have edited the question.